# ng-model is not updating in nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have text-angular embedded in an directive that has the scope variable... scope.htmlContent.content. In the directive I have

```
template:
'''
// This updates just fine. I use it to debug so I will take this out from time to time
<p ng-bind='htmlContent.content'></p>
// ng-model htmlContent.content stays blank and does not update
<text-angular ng-model='htmlContent.content'>
</text-angular>
''',
link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
//some code
$http({
  method: 'GET'
  url: 'someurl.com'
}).success(function(data,headers,config) {
  // This does not update text-angular
  scope.htmlContent.content = data;
  // If I add this, it will error out
  scope.$apply()
})
}
```

Anyway, ng-model is not updating properly. Only when I explicitly set scope.htmlContent.content in the beginning of the link function out side of some async fxn then it works. How can I update ng-model?

Comment: Create a factory for the http call and tgen jnject that factory into the directive

Comment: If you explained a bit more and added this as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: What error do you get on scope.$apply?

Comment: $rootScope is in the middle of digest cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a factory for your http get call something like this:

```
//Please change it as per your needs
app.factory('factoryProvider', function(){
    return {
    yourData:function(callback){
        $http.get('url').success(callback); 
    }
   }
});
```

Then in your directive you need to inject the factory

```
app.directive('myDiv',['factoryProvider', function(factoryProvider) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p>{{name}}</p>',
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.data=factoryProvider.yourData;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: A directive has its own isolated scope. Have you made ngModel as required in the directive?

Comment: I tried, do I have to do something funny with transclution or directive controllers? I get the concepts of isolated scopes, but I'm not so certain how this relates to ngModel.

Comment: It turns out that it wasn't an issue with ng-model. It was an issue with malformed html. But it was coming in as a string so I didn't think it mattered. But anyway, thankyou!